# Executar um SUM numa QUERY - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, query, sum

Galera, gostaria de somar os valores de cada coluna dessa `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)) as Datetime) as Dia,
  ((MAX(EnergiaMensalINV1)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV1))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV2)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV2))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV3)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV3))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV4)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV4))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV5)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV5))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV6)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV6))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV7)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV7))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV8)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV8))) as Usina,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV1)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV1)) AS INV1,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV2)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV2)) AS INV2 ,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV3)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV3)) AS INV3,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV4)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV4)) AS INV4,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV5)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV5)) AS INV5,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV6)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV6)) AS INV6,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV7)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV7)) AS INV7,
  (MAX(EnergiaMensalINV8)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV8)) AS INV8
FROM Estatisticos
WHERE ((E3TimeStamp BETWEEN '01-12-2022' AND '21-12-2022') AND EnergiaMensalINV1>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV2>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV3>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV4>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV5>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV6>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV7>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV8>0)
GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)) as datetime)
ORDER BY Dia ASC
```

Quando uso `SUM` em cada linha, apresenta esse erro:

> SQL Error [130] [S0001]: Não é possível executar uma função de
> agregação em uma expressão que contenha uma agregação ou uma
> subconsulta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para somar os valores de cada coluna, você pode usar a função SUM em conjunto com a cláusula OVER, que permite aplicar uma função de agregação sobre uma janela de resultados.

Veja como ficaria o código:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)) as Datetime) as Dia,
  ((MAX(EnergiaMensalINV1)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV1))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV2)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV2))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV3)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV3))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV4)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV4))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV5)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV5))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV6)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV6))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV7)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV7))+(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV8)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV8))) as Usina,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV1)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV1)) OVER() AS INV1,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV2)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV2)) OVER() AS INV2 ,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV3)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV3)) OVER() AS INV3,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV4)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV4)) OVER() AS INV4,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV5)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV5)) OVER() AS INV5,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV6)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV6)) OVER() AS INV6,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV7)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV7)) OVER() AS INV7,
  SUM(MAX(EnergiaMensalINV8)-MIN(EnergiaMensalINV8)) OVER() AS INV8
FROM Estatisticos
WHERE ((E3TimeStamp BETWEEN '01-12-2022' AND '21-12-2022') AND EnergiaMensalINV1>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV2>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV3>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV4>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV5>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV6>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV7>0 AND EnergiaMensalINV8>0)
GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)) as datetime)
ORDER BY Dia ASC
```

Comment: PERFEITO!!
Rodou certinho, muito agradecido!